# Colors are different when SSHing onto a Linux machine from iTerm2. How can I standardize them?

Tags: terminal, ssh, iterm, color

Currently, when I SSH onto a Linux machine, the `ls` output colors and syntax coloring in VIM are different from the colors on my local machine. The colors shown are not defined in my `Profile...Colors...ANSI Colors`, and include an ugly dark brown color for "yellow."

How can I force the text from a remote session to match my ANSI colors, so the coloring is always consistent?

Here's an example of what I'm talking about: left is VIM session on my local computer, right is VIM session within an SSH session. Notice the hideous brown.

[image]

And here's an example of the `ls` problem -- the colors are different.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to the "ls colors are different" problem. You just need to make sure `ls` coloring is enabled on both machines, then use [this page](https://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/) to make the colors encoded in the local (Mac) `LSCOLORS` variable identical to the colors encoded in the remote (Linux) `LS_COLORS` variable.

For Linux `ls` coloring matching the macOS defaults: put this in your `.bashrc` on your Mac:

```
alias ls="ls -G"
export LSCOLORS="exfxcxdxbxegedabagacad"
```

And put this in your `.bashrc` on the Linux machine:

```
alias ls="ls --color=always"
export LS_COLORS="di=34:ln=35:so=32:pi=33:ex=31:bd=34;46:cd=34;43:su=30;41:sg=30;46:tw=30;42:ow=30;43"
```

---

Edit: Alternatively (this is what I now do), you can just download "coreutils" with [homebrew](https://brew.sh) via `brew install coreutils`, then place `alias ls=gls` in your `.bashrc`. `gls` is the GNU version. Now, you can control `ls` colors with `LS_COLORS`, just like on Linux.

Also, if you want to get even more fancy: since you are now using the GNU `ls`, you can control the colors of various file extensions/types/permission levels by creating a `~/.dircolors.ansi` file and running `gdircolors ~/.dircolors.ansi`. [This repo](https://github.com/seebi/dircolors-solarized) has some dircolors templates to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

The VIM part of this question was answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414395/112647).

Turns out my local session had `background` set to `dark` in VIM, and my remote session had `background` set to `light`. I just added the line `set background=dark` in my `.vimrc` and the colors now look identical.

Comment: I have `set background=dark` in .vimrc, but before `colorscheme`, now switching the order fixed this issue.